# How to restore applications from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, backup, itunes

My Mac crashed last week. I was able to get some of the data from the Time Machine backup. However, during the time between the last backup and the crash I bought some applications, which are now on my iPhone, but they are not in iTunes.

Is there any way I could restore the newest applications from my iPhone to iTunes?

Thanks for your ideas!

kind regards,
Jakub

Comment: This is not programming related. It should be moved to superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redownload them with the same iTunes account, as already suggested. The other option is to transfer them directly from the phone.

If you open iTunes with the iPhone connected, then right click on the device (or control-click if you have a one button mouse), and select "Transfer Purchases"

To transfer purchases, you will need to "Authorise" your computer to do so - you can do this 5 times total - though once a computer is authorised it will allow you to transfer the purchases until you uninstall iTunes.

(I believe you can also reset all of your authorisations, but having not had to do so yet I don't know the process for that)

Answer (score 1):

Redownload them with the same iTunes account, you won't be charged again, it is Apple policy...